# Honeycomb Networked Functions

Tags: android, networking, android-asynctask, handler, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm trying to make a Android Honeycomb tablet app for a social website. I created a class to hold various API functions, like this one:

```
public String getBlogInfo(String blogName)
```

which contains HttpGet and other networked things. I'm calling that function from the main thread like so:

```
APIHelper apiHelp = new APIHelper();

String blogInfo = apiHelp.getBlogInfo(blog);
```

Of course, after receiving the error NetworkOnMainThreadException and doing a little research I found that I need to use Handlers or AsyncTasks to pull this off properly. I just really don't know how I would start. I would love a nudge in the right direction, and if you need more of my code I'll be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good solution here:

http://ajeyasharma.com/2010/04/returning-values-from-asynctask.html

Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

In Honeycomb, you cannot perform network related activity in the main thread. So, you either need to create a new thread for network related activity or use AsyncTasks.

You might probably want to look at http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I already knew that. I just don't know how to use AsyncTasks and neither of those links (which I had already read) did much to clear it up. I was looking for a better explanation.